# Collect a lot of data from an Angular form

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, angular-forms

I need to collect all the answers that the user selects within a form.

The idea is that I create a series of ion-items from an object that I'm going through. Now I need to control the user's responses, and somehow save these responses. For this I must know at all times that for the object [n] which of the two options is marked.

```
<form (submit)="doSubmitAnswer(????????)">
        <ion-list text-wrap radio-group *ngFor="let Quest of navParams.data.question">
          <ion-list-header>
            {{Quest.statement}}
          </ion-list-header>
          <ion-item *ngIf="Quest.answer1 !== undefined">
            <ion-label >{{ Quest.answer1 }}</ion-label>
            <ion-radio  value="{{ Quest.answer1 }}" checked="false"></ion-radio>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item *ngIf="Quest.answer2 !== undefined">
              <ion-label >{{ Quest.answer2 }}</ion-label>
              <ion-radio  value="{{ Quest.answer2 }}" checked="false"></ion-radio>
       </ion-list>
<button ion-button full type="submit" id="click">ENVIAR</button>
</form>
```

The idea would be to get something like this [answer1, answer1, answer2, answer2, answer1, ...] so I can work with this information.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have a multi step form?

Comment: No. I'm quite new of this frameworks. That is all I have.

Comment: Why is 'answer' not an array? If so you could use ngFor for this as well.

Comment: I decided to do like that because was easy to me to save the information to a BBDD.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can use **Reactive Forms**. Reactive forms creates two way binding between your view and model so whenever you change any input in your view your corresponding object will automatically change.

To give you an idea, in your case it would be something like this:

**In your component:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-profile-editor',
  templateUrl: './profile-editor.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./profile-editor.component.css']
})
export class SampleComponent {
  yourForm = new FormGroup({
    firstSegment: new FormGroup({
      firstAnswer: new FormControl(''),
      secondAnswer: new FormControl('')
    }),
    secondSegment: new FormGroup({
      firstAnswer: new FormControl(''),
      secondAnswer: new FormControl('')
    })
  });
}
```

**And in your view:**

```
<form [formGroup]="yourForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(yourForm.value)">
  <div formGroupName="firstSegment"> 
    <label>
      Question 1:
      <input type="text" formControlName="firstAnswer">
    </label>

    <label>
      Question 2:
      <input type="text" formControlName="secondAnswer">
    </label>
  </div>

  <div formGroupName="secondSegment"> 
    <label>
      Question 1:
      <input type="text" formControlName="firstAnswer">
    </label>

    <label>
      Question 2:
      <input type="text" formControlName="secondAnswer">
    </label>
  </div>
</form>
```

You can access your form's each control value by using

`this.yourForm.get("yourControlName").value`

for using them in your `if` statements

In this way all your responses will automatically save in your form and you can access your entire form data by using

`yourForm.value`

More on Reactive Forms [here](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms)

Also have a look at Nested forms [here](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#creating-nested-form-groups)

Comment: Thank you for the help. But the problem is as I create all the `ion-list` using: `*ngFor` I can not create that `div` `ids`. It should be something dynamic.

Comment: So you are saying that you are adding the controls dynamically through loop instead of hard-coding them in the component?

Comment: I don't get you. I'm creating them using *ngFor

Answer (score 0):

After searching on the web, and read several post about `Angular` and `*ngFor` I've seen that you can iterate over two variables. Therefore, I create a variable `i`, and when I click on an `item`, I call a function which is responsible for saving the information in a `vector`.

```
<ion-list text-wrap radio-group *ngFor="let Quest of navParams.data.question; let i =index">
      <ion-item *ngIf="Quest.answer1 !== undefined">
        <ion-label >{{ Quest.answer1 }}</ion-label>
        <ion-radio  (click)="saveanswer(Quest.answer1,i)" checked="false"></ion-radio>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item *ngIf="Quest.answer2 !== undefined">
        <ion-label >{{ Quest.answer2 }}</ion-label>
        <ion-radio  (click)="saveanswer(Quest.answer2,i)" checked="false"></ion-radio>
      </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```